# Как создать нейросеть для создания музыки

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Нужно сделать нейронную сеть, которая будет продолжать песню. Можно ли реaлизвать нейросеть следующим способом: единственный нейрон входного слоя будет отвечать за время, нейроны выходного слоя будут выдавать музыку? Если да, то как преобразовать mp3 в числа и наоборот? Если нет, то как можно реализовать это?

Comment: Вашим способом можно реализовать, но она просто будет запоминать музыку которую вы подали на обучение. Попробуйте использовать RNN. А на выходе вы можете выдавать различные частоты, то есть ноты. Сохранение можно реализовать с помощью pyaudio например или других библиотек.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/music_generation?hl=ru посмотрите этот официальный пример от tensorflow может чем нибудь поможет.